# Errors concerning update-manager every time I try to install any kind of package

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

Every time I try to install a package using apt or apt-get, I get the following error :

```
sudo apt-get install alien
[sudo] Mot de passe de nada : 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
alien est déjà la version la plus récente (8.95).
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
3 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
Paramétrage de update-notifier-common (3.192.1.7) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 38, in <module>
    import chardet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet update-notifier-common (--configure) :
 installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de update-notifier :
 update-notifier dépend de update-notifier-common (= 3.192.1.7) ; cependant :
 Le paquet update-notifier-common n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet update-notifier (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de update-manager :
 update-manager dépend de update-notifier ; cependant :
 Le paquet update-notifier n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet update-manager (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Aucun rapport « apport » n'a été créé car le message d'erreur indique une erreur consécutive à un échec précédent.
                                  Aucun rapport « apport » n'a été créé car le message d'erreur indique une erreur consécutive à un échec précédent.
                                                                    Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 update-manager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to do the same thing as people who encountered the same problem, but with different processes errors like

```
oracle-java8-installer
 libgeronimo-jms-1.1-spec-java
 ant
 javahelp2
 bnd
 junit4
 libistack-commons-java
 libnb-java5-java
 aspectj
 antlr3
```

but that didn't work. Help please.

Comment: Did you run `dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: Yes I did and I get the same errors relative to update-manager

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 update-manager

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1156143/edit) your question to show us the complete output. The summaries lack important detail that we need to help you.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope I can get help because am stuck in this problem since a long period of time.